# How to fix “\app\src\main\res\drawable-v24\ic_launcher_foreground.xml:1: error: not well-formed (invalid token)."

Tags: android-studio

I cant see my error it says `"C:\Users\Louie\AndroidStudioProjects\Appthrough\app\src\main\res\drawable-v24\ic_launcher_foreground.xml:1: error: not well-formed (invalid token)."`

I have looked simpler code but none explain my problem 
    /*
     * Copyright 2018 the original author or authors.
     *
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     * You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     * limitations under the License.
     */

```
package org.gradle.api;

import org.gradle.api.provider.Provider;

/**
 * Provides a domain object of the given type.
 *
 * @param <T>type of domain object
 * @since 4.10
 */
public interface NamedDomainObjectProvider<T> extends Provider<T> {
    /**
     * Configures the domain object with the given action. Actions are run in the order added.
     *
     * @param action A {@link Action} that can configure the domain object when required.
     * @since 4.10
     */
    void configure(Action<? super T> action);

    /**
     * The domain object name referenced by this provider.
     * <p>
     * Must be constant for the life of the object.
     *
     * @return The domain object. Never null.
     * @since 4.10
     */
    String getName();
}
```

Comment: Edit your question with the content of ic_launcher_foreground.xml

Comment: @PraveenPanishetti  Please see update of the question

Comment: You uploaded the wrong code go to C:\Users\Louie\AndroidStudioProjects\Appthrough\app\src\main\res\drawable-v24\ic_launcher_foreground.xml open that ic_launcher_foreground.xml and upload the code present in that file.